# Recursive PostgreSQL dynamic average

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL dynamic averaging problem that I cannot solve:

I have data for individuals with start and finish dates for employment are as follows:

```
"parentid"                               "Name"                "startdate"     "enddate"

"01e7de72-843d-4aa5-b3ae-2e2887d1b342"   "Isabelle Smith"     "2011-05-23"   "2016-04-16"
"027ee658-8c4d-4910-b93e-62c0900f2147"  "Emelie Blogs"        "2012-09-17"   "2016-03-16"
"02cbb478-adf3-4a8b-a5aa-ae9f03943ce4"  "Joshauh Jow"         "2015-04-04"   NULL
"0328f382-2845-4623-a940-ab68af5d11cc"  "VICTORIA Fred"       "2015-05-11"   NULL
"03823a20-51bc-4ae5-ab73-79056355ea36"  "Elin Tree"           "2014-03-24"   NULL   
"03878ef8-1c3a-4310-b3d5-7b8d18634707"  "Michaela Apple"      "2011-07-08"   NULL   
"03c36926-395b-4e3c-9f77-c6214ce763a2"  "Immad Cheese"        "2012-05-15"   NULL   
"0436824c-29a6-4140-ba4a-d0f56facd8fc"  "Burak Teal"          "2009-06-22"   NULL   
"04d7a07a-0ad4-4091-98d2-a7ff35798b6f"  "Roberto Purple"      "2015-03-30"   "2016-03-01"
"04f32c2f-887f-4e03-be67-bc023aa3a7c2"  "Iftikar Orange"      "2012-06-27"   NULL   
"055b690a-153a-49c8-8ac0-112681f79551"  "Josef Red"           "2014-02-21"   "2016-04-13"
"055be2f6-baec-4626-b876-7ff16dc95464"  "Harry Green"         "2016-03-27"   NULL   
"05a570b0-ec76-49d9-a742-5bf08f215fec"  "Sofie Blue"          "2010-06-15"   "2016-05-16"
"05c92e7a-efde-44f0-a57c-298cbe129259"  "BANARAS Yellow"      "2015-06-22"   NULL   
"05fe0113-9bda-407b-bd72-5bf2a9deae15"  "Bengt  Drury"        "2015-03-30"   "2016-06-16"
"063c454f-2e97-48a8-96fc-9e84d29f5d96"  "Son That"            "2016-03-27"   NULL   
"07b76b47-8086-4df6-a3da-50dcfcd2de89"  "Sam This"            "2015-03-21"   "2016-05-24"
"082771ee-2f02-4623-abc2-696447f9f791"  "Felix This"          "2014-11-24"   "2016-05-31"
"08e39639-176b-4f44-ae75-1025219730c6"  "ROBIN That"          "2015-10-26"   NULL   
"09ab8491-9d9a-4091-b448-8315e3b5d3f0"  "Kaziah This"         "2016-05-14"   NULL   
"0a74dd0c-e1ee-4b32-a893-c486f7402363"  "Luke Him"            "2015-12-16"   NULL   
"0b098799-7d92-47df-9778-b48edf948af9"  "MARIA Her"           "2015-05-11"   NULL   
"0b480b25-8d2b-441b-8039-48b4e9188769"  "That Adebayor"       "2015-04-09"   NULL   
"0b86b44e-f3e0-4ddf-8e72-e0d7f9470279"  "This Ålund"          "2012-02-07"   "2016-06-05"
"0c3e13d0-f602-41da-b10c-f70072605e63"  "First Ekmark"        "2013-02-08"   NULL   
"0d2367f4-a6b4-4381-b7dc-3e0c9063285f"  "Anna Check"          "2015-03-13"   NULL   
"0e31731b-0384-43ef-adeb-503ad5a137f9"  "Assign Test1"        "2015-05-22"   NULL   
"0e3f8b57-cba2-4240-abd4-d157832ef421"  "Ramises Person       "2016-10-11"   NULL   
"0f6af1c8-7672-4f0b-912c-91675cf52845"  "Lars Surname"        "2016-03-28"   NULL
```

For this report a user would input two dates startOfPeriod and endOfPeriod

I need an SQL statement that for those dynamic dates would give me a week by week output on the number of people who were employed for each week during that period.
(A week would constitute each 7 days from the startOfPeriod date)

Is this possible in PostgreSQL and how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is generate series of week between start and end date, select starting and ending week from employment, then for each week count.
I've not tested it for bound cases but something OP coud starts with

```
WITH startDate(d) as (VALUES ('2010-01-01'::DATE))
   , endDate(d) as (VALUES ('2016-06-06'::DATE))
   , weeks as (select to_char(startDate.d+s.a,'YYYY-WW') as w
               from startDate,endDate,generate_series(0,(endDate.d - startDate.d),7) as s(a))
   , emp as (select name,to_char(sd,'YYYY-WW') as sw
                       , to_char(coalesce(ed,endDate.d),'YYYY-WW') as ew 
             from startDate,endDate,public.so where sd > startDate.d )
SELECT 
   w.w
  ,(select ARRAY_AGG(name) from emp Where w.w BETWEEN sw AND ew ) as emps
  ,(select count(name) from emp Where w.w BETWEEN sw AND ew ) as empCount
FROM weeks w
```

Test setup

```
create table public.so (
  name TEXT
  ,sd DATE
  ,ed DATE
);

INSERT INTO public.so (name,sd,ed) VALUES 
   ('a','2011-05-23','2016-04-16')
  ,('b','2012-09-17','2016-03-16')
  ,('c','2009-12-12',null)
  ,('d','2015-03-30','2016-03-01')
  ,('e','2012-06-27',null)
  ,('f','2014-02-21','2016-04-13')
  ,('g','2016-03-27',null)
  ,('h','2010-06-15','2016-05-16')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the type [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rangetypes.html) and the [overlap operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-range.html).

The first query in `WITH` defines the period, the second generates series of weeks:

```
with period(start_of_period, end_of_period) as (
    values ('2012-01-20'::date, '2012-02-15'::date)
),
weeks as (
    select daterange(d::date, d::date+ 7) a_week
    from period, 
    lateral generate_series (start_of_period, end_of_period, '7d'::interval) d
)
select lower(a_week) start_of_week, count(*)
from weeks
left join a_table
on daterange(startdate, enddate) && a_week
group by 1
order by 1;

 start_of_week | count 
---------------+-------
 2012-01-20    |     4
 2012-01-27    |     4
 2012-02-03    |     5
 2012-02-10    |     5
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Range constructors use inclusive lower and exclusive upper bounds by default. So you need either `daterange(d::date, d::date + 7)` or `daterange(d::date, d::date + 6, '[]')`. Also, ranges can be unbounded, so you don't need to use coalesce ... infinity "hack", except when you really want to exclude infinity values.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the one.